# Nutch: how to feed additional fields to ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, web-crawler, nutch

I'm using Nutch 1.13 and ES 2.4.5 to crawl a specific website and build a replacement of Google Site Search. I'm very new to this so I did not deviate much from default installation/configs/etc. At the end of the day, I have, I guess, a set of standard fields in my ES index:

```
_index, _type, _id, url, title, content
```

and a few others. Only `url`, `title` and `content` are useful for me - I just need full text search for my website. However, I would like to have more fields included in ES. For example, `content-length` or `mime-type` etc - I believe Nutch should have them already somewhere internally, when doing crawling. How to feed them to ES index?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write an [IndexingFilter](https://nutch.apache.org/apidocs/apidocs-1.9/org/apache/nutch/indexer/IndexingFilter.html) plugin to add those fields for indexing.

Your `IndexingFilter` will look something like this:

```
public class AddField implements IndexingFilter {

    private Configuration conf;

    public NutchDocument filter(NutchDocument doc, Parse parse, Text url,
            CrawlDatum datum, Inlinks inlinks) {
        String content = parse.getText();
        doc.add("pageLength", content.length());
        // add more field
        // ...

        return doc;
    }

    //Boilerplate
    public Configuration getConf() {
        return conf;
    }

    //Boilerplate
    public void setConf(Configuration conf) {
        this.conf = conf;
    }
}
```

You can find how to write a similar plugin [here](https://florianhartl.com/nutch-plugin-tutorial.html).